# use angular material in formly

Tags: angular-material, angular-formly

I'm trying to use angular-material in angular-formly but don't know how to. The docs are not very clear. I'm facing problems when trying to make the form layout responsive. The layout breaks when I try to use different types ( input, select, datepicker, etc) on a single line.

Comment: @ Etherealm this [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-formly/material)   will be helpful to you.